# Bilinear maps which are linear maps of products

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V,W$ be $F$-vector spaces, where $V$ has the additional structure of (commutative) vector multiplication $* : V \times V \to V$ (for example, $V = F[X]$).

Suppose $\psi : V \to W$ is a linear map. Then $\varphi : V \times V \to W$,

$$(v_1,v_2) \mapsto \psi(v_1 * v_2)$$

is a bilinear map.

Is there a name for bilinear maps which can be described in this way?

**Remark**: if it was $W$ which had vector multiplication, we could define a bilinear map $(v_1,v_2) \mapsto \psi(v_1)* \psi(v_2)$.

Comment: If you don't require that the multiplication is associative, this is equivalent to asking for a symmetric bilinear map such that the span of the image has dimension at most $\dim V$. I don't know if there's a name for this second condition, it doesn't seem very natural to me. If you require associativity things seem to get much more delicate; I don't know how to classify such maps. What's your motivation for thinking about such maps?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I was working in $\mathbb{R}[X]$ and came across a nice linear map. I thought about extending it to an inner product with the idea above and I wanted to know if there were any general results about such maps I could use. Could you explain the equivalence a little more please? I think one direction is not so clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Given such a bilinear map consider the corresponding linear map $\varphi' : V \otimes V \to W$. Since, by assumption, this map factors through a map $V \otimes V \to V$, it has rank at most $\dim V$. Conversely, given any linear map $\varphi : V \otimes V \to W$ of rank at most $\dim V$, it admits some factorization through $V$. If you want the multiplication $V \otimes V \to V$ to be commutative then you run through this same argument but for symmetric bilinear maps and the symmetric square $S^2(V)$.

I'm not aware of a name for this rank condition; it doesn't seem very natural to me. If you want the multiplication to be associative then I have no idea what can be said as far as a general classification.

The special case you describe in the comments of bilinear forms on $\mathbb{R}[x]$ coming from a linear functional $L : \mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{R}$ is connected to some very classical material; see [umbral calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus) and [orthogonal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials) for much more on this. Briefly, interesting examples of such linear functionals $L$ come from choosing a measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and then taking

$$L(f(x)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \, d \mu$$

which, if $\mu$ has infinite support, induces an inner product on $\mathbb{R}[x]$ given by

$$L(f(x) g(x)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) g(x) \, d \mu.$$

Applying the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to the basis $\{ 1, x, x^2, \dots \}$ of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ then gives a family of polynomials which are orthogonal with respect to the above inner product; these are the **orthogonal polynomials** of the measure $\mu$. This recovers many classical families of interesting polynomials that show up in various branches of mathematics and many interesting computations are possible from here. You can see, for example, my old blog post *[Moments, Hankel determinants, orthogonal polynomials, Motzkin paths, and continued fractions](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/moments-hankel-determinants-orthogonal-polynomials-motzkin-paths-and-continued-fractions/)* for some examples.

Comment: "Conversely, given any linear map φ:V⊗V→W of rank at most dimV, it admits some factorization through V." This is the part that doesn't strike me as immediately obvious. It has been a while since I did linear algebra (and also, my brain is a little fried today) so it might just be me. I was indeed working with umbral calculus, deriving some results related to falling factorials. Thanks for the links.

Comment: @legionwhale: consider the image factorization $V \otimes V \to \text{im}(\varphi) \to W$. By hypothesis $\dim \text{im}(\varphi) \le \dim V$. So pick any embedding $\text{im}(\varphi) \to V$, then quotient by any complement to the image of that embedding, getting a factorization $\text{im}(\varphi) \to V \to \text{im}(\varphi)$. This can also be written out more explicitly in terms of choosing bases and so forth. The point is that if we don't require associativity etc. then $V$ is just some vector space and its dimension is the only constraint on what kind of maps we can write using it.

Comment: The general claim, which is maybe easier to understand if the different vector spaces involved have different names, is that if $f : V \to W$ is any linear map then it admits some factorization through a third vector space $U$ iff $\dim \text{im}(f) \le \dim U$.

Comment: I see; in my mind, I was implicitly assuming the associativity. I am quite intrigued that the idea (supposing associative multiplication) may not have been considered more generally outside of $\mathbb{R}[X] \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in that direction, at least. I think it ought to be interesting to do this for the Weyl algebra and this should have some combinatorial applications; I had this idea years ago but never sat down to actually write anything out.